# MACD histogram with a finer resolution

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have a strategy that I'm querying on the histogram of the MACD. Unfortunately, the alarms are always executed one time unit later in Tadingview. In many cases, this leads to mistrades. So I try to run the histogram and MACD in a smaller timeframe to trigger the long or short decision before the actual time interval. So that the trade is executed on the right candle. Is there the possibility to let the MACD run on a smaller time unit? Or is there a possibility to create the histogram in smaller units to trigger the trade to a candle beforehand? Or is it possible to trigger a trade in real time when creating the candle?

```
fastl=12
slowl=26
macdl=9

MACD=ta.ema(close,fastl)-ta.ema(close,slowl)
signal=ta.ema(MACD,macdl)
hist=MACD-signal

plot(hist,title="MACD_hist",style=plot.style_histogram,color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255), linewidth=7)
plot(MACD, title="MACD_line",color=color.blue)
plot(signal,title="signal_line",color=color.orange)

long_beding = hist >= hist[1]
short_beding = hist <= hist[1]

if(long_beding and barstate.isconfirmed) 
    alertLongEntry = input.string("Entry Long {{ticker}}!", "Alert Message Long Entry: ", group = "Alert Settings")
    strategy.entry("GL", strategy.long, alert_message = alertLongEntry)

if(short_beding and barstate.isconfirmed)  //and time_is_allowed
    alertShortEntry = input.string("Entry Short {{ticker}}!", "Alert Message Short Entry: ", group = "Alert Settings")
    strategy.entry("GS", strategy.short, alert_message = alertShortEntry)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you use **barstate.isconfirmed** which implies that your condition can only be met on the last (closing) update of the current bar with long_beding = true.
That's why your strategy.entry execute only AFTER the bar is closed.

If you remove **barstate.isconfirmed** in your code, you strategy.enter will be executed as soon as long_beding=true.

**In real time :** each time the value is updated, the script is run (so several time during a bar formation)

**In backtest :** if you don't have the premium version, the script will executed only at the end of the bar formation.